# Match pattern and append at the end of line using sed

Tags: linux

I have a bunch of lines for example:

```
hello.c                                 
Untitled Folder          
Shell.sh          
Linux
```

and so on

what I want is to append `/` at the end of lines which do not contain `.` using sed. i.e.

```
hello.c                                                                                                                   
Untitled Folder/     
Shell.sh     
Linux/
```

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an address:

```
sed -e '/\./!s=$=/='
```

Which means: if the line does not (`!`) contain a dot (`/\./`), append /.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
files = ['hello.c', 'Untitled Folder', 'Shell.sh', 'Linux']
for i, f in enumerate(files):
    if '.' not in f:
        files[i] = "%s/" % f

print files
```

ouput:

```
['hello.c', 'Untitled Folder/', 'Shell.sh', 'Linux/']
```